# How to fix Wine Staging installation problem? Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: wine

I've looked at every possible forum and still can't figure out why this is happening:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.4~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I've uninstalled wine multiple times and reinstalled it multiple times to combat this issue, but nothing has helped. Can anyone please help me fix this so I can rip some Overwatch.

Edit: Used lutris alternatively, can now play OW.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: yeah, I've tried most of the methods found online such as purging wine, and using lutris, nothing's worked man